# Javascript framework or technology to facilitate creation of partial HTML

Tags: javascript, frameworks

Often I find myself creating some partial views for a webpage which can be populated by some set of data `e` and subsequently attached to a given element `attachable` like so:

```
function mySection(e, attachable){

  this.$mySection = $('<section>',{
    class:'mySection'
  });

  $('<span>',{
    text:e.someRelevantInformation
  }).appendTo(this.$mySection);

  this.$mySection.appendTo(attachable);
}
```

and then call the function:

```
mySection(someJSON, $(' body '));
```

Usually these sort of partial views have several categories or subsections, and sometimes even have nested partial views within them.  Using JQuery like this is infinitely more scalable than doing something like

```
document.findElementById('mySection').append('<section><span>'+e.someText+'</span></section>');
```

or something of the sort.  So are there any frameworks or technologies or even just personal techniques that take this even further?  Ideally I would like something as seamless as Rails' `.erb` files, but I'm looking for an extension to Javascript, not HTML.

**Edit**

I should clarify that it's important to be able to dynamically generate these one after another, resulting in, in some cases, dozens of sections based on templates.

Comment: mustache can do all that and is light and fast... there's also ejs, an erb rip-off

Comment: Thanks!  I'll look at these and I'll post back here later with some examples.

Comment: There is an official JQuery Template plugin, that alleviates some of the difficulty associated with generating repetitive elements programatically: https://github.com/BorisMoore/jquery-tmpl

Comment: Does mustache hold up well when using larger objects with several layers of nested data?  despite looking at the documentation, it seems extremely cumbersome when I have more than 2 or 3 layers of data.

Comment: So far I'm having the most success with EJS.  I'll just post some examples of that here later.